# Example of progress and preservation failing in a commonly used programming language like Java

Tags: programming-languages, lambda-calculus

I am wondering if my solution is correct or I am on the right track. I have searched online and found a paper about [Java type system being unsound](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2983990.2984004) but that doesn't really answer the progress and preservation issue.

Question:

Give a non-obvious problem in the language definition that would prevent “progress”
from being true.

Give a non-obvious problem in the language definition that would prevent “preservation” from being true.

My attempt:

Progress:
If $· \vdash e : τ$ then either $e \to e'$ for some $e'$ or $e$ is a value.

```java
class A {
 String name;
 String getName() { return this.name; };
}

A a = null;
String b = a.getName(); // we don't get to another evaluation step nor we get to a value
```

I think this is correct because the expression doesn't evaluate to another expression nor do we get a value ... and the program crashes.

Preservation:
If $· \vdash e : τ$ and $e \to e'$ then $· \vdash e' : τ$

```java
class A {
 String name;
 String getName() { return (String)((Object)12); };
}

A a = new A();
String b = a.getName(); // after evaluation of RHS, the assignment is not really valid
```

This one I am not so confident. The up-cast to object and down-cast to integer cause the assignment to not type check.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: I gave similar feedback on your prior question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/156662/slr-parse-table-construction-for-left-recursive-grammar#comment329463_156662

Comment: @D.W. I can't just ask a question without showing my attempt. Please edit the question.

Comment: What's missing from your question is a reason why you think your answer might not be correct. By the way, if this is an exercise from the book *Types and Programming Languages*, please say the chapter and question number and which page it is found on, and give the proper context (chances are, the question is asking about *Featherweight Java*, not the full Java language). If the question is not from that book, the [tag:types-and-programming-languages] tag is incorrect.

Comment: @kaya3 I updated the question

Comment: Progress for a language with computational effects (such as exceptions, mutable state, and other things that Java also has) must be phrased differently frok what you wrote. It is: if $\cdot \vdash e : \tau$ then $e$ is a value, $e$ triggers and effect (such as an exception), or $e$ can make a step to some $e'$.

Answer (score 2):

The definitions of progress and preservation used in the question only really make sense in the context of term-rewriting, but there is no canonical definition of Java's semantics in that form. It may be possible to define Java's semantics in such a way that your answers are correct, but it is possible to define Java's semantics in such a way that they aren't, because "throwing an exception" could still count as progress. To expand on that, the Java Language Specification defines what it means for an [expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.6) or [statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1) to "complete normally" by producing a value (or no value for a statement), or to "complete abruptly" with some control-flow effect.

If we define Java as a term-rewriting system where "value" means what we traditionally call a value, then your first answer seems correct, but your second answer doesn't. Specifically:

- The term `(String)((Object) 12)` has type `String`,
- After one evaluation step the term becomes `(String)(new Integer(12))`, which still has type `String`,
- There is no further evaluation step; the program next throws a `ClassCastException`, and throwing an exception means the expression does not produce a value in the traditional sense.

For preservation to fail, there must be progress to some term which does not have the correct type. At this point in your example there is no further progress, so there is no failure of preservation.

---

However, I think this definition of Java's semantics is flawed, because it does not account for statements such as `return 5;`, `break;` or `throw new Exception();` which "complete abruptly". If Java must be defined as a term-rewriting system (which sounds like a monumental undertaking), it should be done in a different way, more in the spirit of the Java Language Specification.

- Let the "values" in our system be $\mathrm{Normal}(v)$  where $v$ is a value in the traditional sense (or some [unit value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type), for statements which complete normally without producing values in the traditional sense), and $\mathrm{Abrupt}(e)$ where $e$ is a control-flow effect, such as returning, breaking, or throwing an exception.
- $\mathrm{Normal}(v)$ has type $T$ if $v: T$ in the traditional sense, and $\mathrm{Abrupt}(e)$ has type $\bot$, meaning it has type $T$ for all $T$.

Then, your examples each evaluate to $\mathrm{Abrupt}(\dots)$, specifically the first throws a `NullPointerException` and the second throws a `ClassCastException`. Each of these is a "value" (progress), and each has type $\bot$ implying they also have type `String`, as required (preservation).

With this more robust definition of Java's semantics, though, we can still give examples where both progress and preservation fail:

- Progress fails for the statement `while(true) {}`. There is no evaluation step to take for this statement, but it is not a "value". (Technically, this depends on how the semantics have been defined; We could add a rule saying that `while(true) {}` is rewritten as `while(true) {}` in which case there is technically "progress" because some rule is applicable, but the program obviously diverges.)
- Preservation fails precisely if Java's type system is unsound; [this is the *definition* of an unsound type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). You have found a paper discussing this, so I won't go into further detail.

Comment: Progress and preservation definitely makes sense *outside* the context of term rewriting, quite generally for programming languages.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Progress and preservation are both defined in terms of an evaluation step $e \to e'$, where $e'$ is necessarily the same kind of thing as $e$. When $e$ and $e'$ are expressions or statements, as in this question and as is generally the case, the evaluation step rewrites terms as other terms. It is possible to instead define an evaluation step where $e$ and $e'$ are program states (e.g. an instruction pointer, stack state and heap state), but in that case it does not really make sense to talk about the types of $e$ and $e'$.

Comment: @kaya3 This definition of progress and preservation apply for languages whose semantics are defined operationally, with the use of an evaluation relation. But semantics of a language can be defined in various ways, and then the type safety statement changes accordingly.

Comment: @frabala OK - I've edited the first sentence to refer to the definitions of progress and preservation given in the question (which I believe are defined for term-rewriting systems), as opposed to the concepts of progress and preservation which can be interpreted more broadly. If there are further edits necessary, please suggest.

Comment: I am not getting involved in a pointless discussion about "what is a term rewriting system". There is no need to gatekeep such a beautiful theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Progress and preservation are properties of a semantics, not of a language. It's possible to define a programming language in different ways which do not necessarily all have the same properties. Both are properties of semantics defined by an evaluation relation (either a partial evaluation as in small-step semantics or a complete evaluation as in big-step semantics).

The point of progress is to ensure that the semantics is well-defined on all programs that are considered valid. It says that any valid program evaluates to something. The opposite of progress is that there are valid programs that do not have a well-defined semantics: depending on the language, this can mean:

- that the semantics is not precise enough to fully describe the language;
- or that some programs encounter a fatal error (which could actually be modelled in the semantics by defining “fatal error” as a special “value” $\bot$);
- or that some programs have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): programs for which the semantics does not specify the behavior are unpredictable and can do anything — which is really bad.

The progress property only addresses valid programs. It's pointless to try to give a semantics for programs that the compiler would reject. Typing is a convenient way of defining valid programs: well-typed programs are valid, and ill-typed programs are invalid. The compiler rejects ill-typed programs, and this way all well-typed programs are valid. In this perspective, preservation is mostly useful for small-step semantics, where the semantics of a program is a sequence of programs (or program states) obtained by successive rewriting. Preservation says that if you evaluate a valid programs, all the intermediate evaluation steps yield valid programs. And progress says that at each step, there is a way to continue evaluating.

Java does not have undefined behavior. (At least not until you get into dark corners such as linking with programs written in other languages.) Ill-typed programs like `"a" * "b"` or calling a method that doesn't exist have well-defined behavior: they throw an exception which is documented in the language definition. You can express the language definition with a small-step semantics where the intermediate states include the state of the whole memory. This semantics does have the progress and preservation properties. The “trick” is that the type system in this semantics is not Java's full type system: it's a type system where all objects have the same type, since it's always possible to attempt a cast at runtime. (In earlier versions of Java, there were also built-in types like `int` that could not be cast to objects or vice versa. I believe that this is no longer the case in more recent versions.)

If you take Java's runtime types into account, evaluation does not preserve types. You might certainly want to define a semantics that takes all types into account and where evaluation does preserve types. This can let you guarantee that programs don't throw certain exceptions. It certainly is useful to know that your program won't throw a `ClassCastException` or a `NullPointerException`. But then your semantics will not cover the full language. Catching a `ClassCastException` is often bad practice, but it's well-defined and it is occasionally the right thing to do.